# How to call PostgreSQL function with array of rowtype as parameter from Java

Tags: postgresql, jdbc, types, row, spring-jdbc

How to call a postgres function with array of rowtype as parameter from Java application (the application is a Spring web application)?
Of course I can refactor my function and use several arrays of primitive types, but then on application side function call will be ugly.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION process_orders
(
  order_array orders[]
)
RETURNS bigint AS
$BODY$
BEGIN
    -- bla bla bla :)
    RETURN 0;
END;
$BODY$

LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I expect a function-like [row constructor](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-expressions.html#SQL-SYNTAX-ROW-CONSTRUCTORS) won't work for JDBC. Use the **text representation** of said parameter instead.
For instance, if your table is `tbl (id int, txt text)`:

```
SELECT process_orders('{"(1,txt)","(1,txt)"}')
```

Or (to be unambiguous in the face of overloaded functions):

```
SELECT process_orders('{"(1,txt)","(1,txt)"}'::tbl[])
```

Example with space and special character:

```
SELECT process_orders('"(1,txt)","(1,\"txt with space and '\")"}')
```

#### How to determine correct syntax?

Just let Postgres show you:
[**SQL Fiddle.**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!15/9d8b2/1)